# Limit HM-10 (bluetooth 4.0) to just one connection

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, connection, hm-10

I have created an application with an Arduino and a IOS app and they're communicating over Bluetooth 4.0 (HM-10). The communication works fine, but I want to limit the 7 possible connections to just one connection. If one device is connected to the HM-10, it has to be impossible for other devices to find the HM-10 while scanning.

Is het possible to limit the amount of connections?

I have read all the AT commands for the HM-10, but did not find any command to get this done. The only command that I have found was to see if the HM-10 is connected to a device (STATE pin is HIGH).

Rik

Comment: Hi Rik, I use HM-10 as peripheral role, when a central device connect to my HM-10 other device(such iOS & Android) cannot find it in search, I want to connect with multiple cellphone to HM-10 in peripheral role, is it possible ?